# Managing HTTP high volume request

Tags: http, tcp, httpclient, real-time, pool

Establishing a fresh HTTP connection over TCP IP is always very heavy task, especially if there are many routers involved in between two peers.

I need to handle high volume of incoming HTTP requests and forward the same HTTP request to one remote server.

Although routers save routing information, but I think reusing (pools) already created Connection is wise, to save repetitive IO operations. But that would keep threads waiting for connection to be available in pool. But the response should be real time.

What can be best solution here (preferably using java only, but any other solution will do too).

Comment: You could try with a higher value of KeepAlive timeout (assuming Apache is involved). On the other hand, for long lived connections, your remote server should also support them and not close it after some timeout. Look into WebSockets or node.js kind of approach also.

Comment: routers have very little to do with the speed of establishing new http connections.

Comment: @Evert routers have nothing to do with HTTP. It is a layer 3 device, ie. it works with IP.  We use TCP IP to send HTTP requests.